# Return one2many values but product shows different in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am trying to create quotation based on order request, While select the order request number, those requested products has to append in order lines of quotation.

I tried the following code it works, It returned correct product id. but while display in `one2many` field the product is different, I given print option before return it shows correct product.

```
def request_change(self, req_id):
        print req_id
        vals=[]
        refunds = self.env['purchase.request.products'].search([('request_id', '=', req_id)])
        for recs in refunds:
            print recs.name.name
            print recs.name.id
            vals.append({'product_id':recs.id,'name':recs.name.name,'product_qty':1.000,'date_planned':datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'price_unit':recs.name.list_price})
        print vals
        return {'value': {'order_line':vals }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct format of One2many write:

```
(0,0, {}) or (0, False, {})
```

For example:

```
'order_line': [(0,0, {'product_id': 1, 'name': 'Test1'}).....]
```

Try with following code.

```
def request_change(self, req_id):
    print req_id
    vals=[]
    refunds = self.env['purchase.request.products'].search([('request_id', '=', req_id)])
    for recs in refunds:
        vals.append([0,0, {'product_id':recs.id,'name':recs.name.name,'product_qty':1.000,'date_planned':datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'price_unit':recs.name.list_price}])
    return {'value': {'order_line':vals }}
```